# Make row take up remaining space in height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

.row2 is a fixed height footer that is stuck to the bottom of the window. I would like to make .row1 take up all remaining height in the window so the image inside of it can grow as large as the .row1 height.

I'm unable to figure out how to do this, even with flexbox.

Simplified html structure I have is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row1">This row takes up remaining space in height, image should scale up to touch footer
        <br />
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div class="row2">Fixed height footer always stuck to bottom of window</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/1swdf6eh/5/

Comment: juwt add width 100%;http://jsfiddle.net/1swdf6eh/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fixed height for `.row2`. So you can use `calc(100% - 180px)` for the `.row1`

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.row1 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ececec;
  height: calc(100% - 180px);
}
img {
  height: 100%;
}
.row2 {
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row1">This row takes up remaining space in height, image should scale up to touch footer
    <br />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" />
  </div>
  <div class="row2">Fixed height footer always stuck to bottom of window</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that browser support for `calc()` isn't 100%. If you need to support IE8 and older Android browsers you'll have issues. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc. Still, that's much better support than flexbox has so probably the best option. Also, in terms of using `calc()`, always make sure you leave a space either side of the operator e.g. `calc(100% - 180px);` not `calc(100%-180px);` - that has caught me out a couple of times in the past...

Comment: Thanks Michael :) You have reduced my time with very useful info. Indeed it is better than flex box at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to set row2 absolute?? Try spliting the wrapper height by %, so rather than giving row2 180 px, give it height 5% and remove absolution positioning, and give row1 height 95%